# how to add extend time when press E in keyboard?

Tags: javascript

when the user presses "Enter" this code is perfect. but how to add extend time when the user presses "E" by keyboard?

```js
var generalTime = "12";
var extendTime = "5";
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13)//key code for 'Enter'
    {
        var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(generalTime <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML = "Finished";
            } else {
                document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML = generalTime;
                if(generalTime <= 5 && generalTime >= 3){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].style.color = "red";
                }
            }
            generalTime -= 1;
        }, 1000);
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="boxOne">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="quote">Start</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to increase `generalTime` if you want to extend the duration.

Here I added an `else if` that checks if the key was the E key. I've swapped out `e.keyCode` in favor of `e.code` because keyCode is actually [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

```js
let generalTime = 12;
let extendTime = 5;
let downloadTimer;

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.code === "Enter")
    {
        downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(generalTime <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML = "Finished";
            } else {
                document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML = generalTime;
                if(generalTime <= 5 && generalTime >= 3){
                    document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].style.color = "red";
                }
            }
            generalTime -= 1;
        }, 1000);
    } else if (e.code === "KeyE") {
        generalTime += extendTime;
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="boxOne">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="quote">Start</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please also use numbers instead of strings here, I've replaced `"12"` and `"5"` with numbers. You are using them as numbers, so why not use actual numbers?